# How can I know if the current opened page is a post page and not category or archive page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, widget, blogger, blogspot

I'm creating a gadjet for Blogger(blogspot), this widget will be placed on all pages(post,archive and coutegory pages) but I need to get the url of the current opened post only(not category page, not archive page not any other kind of pages).

I only use javascript code in my gadjet so I need to do that in JS.

In other words how can I know if the current page is post page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can some information about the current page on the `location` global variable:

```
>>> location.href
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288422/how-can-i-know-if-the-current-opened-page-is-a-post-page-and-not-category-or-arc/8288481#8288481"
>>> location.pathname
"/questions/8288422/how-can-i-know-if-the-current-opened-page-is-a-post-page-and-not-category-or-arc/8288481"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy once you find out what is the URL pattern of posts and other resources. This simple function does the trick:

```
function isPostUrl(url) {
  return url.match(/^http:\/\/.*\.blogspot.com\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/.*\.html$/) != null
}
```

(probably can be improved, I am not JavaScript/regex guru). This simply checks whether the URL matches post address pattern, something like `http://foo.blogger.com/YYYY/MM/beautified-title.html`.

A little bit of testing (shameless surreptitious):

```
isPostUrl("http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/11/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html")  //true
isPostUrl("http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/search/label/spring")  //false
isPostUrl("http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011_11_01_archive.html")  //false
```

Obviously you use it in companion with `window.location.href`:

```
if(isPostUrl(window.location.href)) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Actually I already thought about this but I'm not sure if this is a good way. Something else is the URL always have blogspot.com?